# How to add item in every N items of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

In the initial stage, i have an object array:

```
[
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit'},
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'fruit' }
]
```

I want to insert :

1) object: {type: 'toys'} in every 5 items with type: all

2) object: {type: 'clothes'} in every 2 items with type: 'fruit'

**Expected Result:**

```
[
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit'},
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'toys' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'clothes' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'clothes' }
]
```

How can i implement this function ? I tried to forEach to add the items, but after pushing an item, the array_demo length is changed and hard to measure which is the next original item of the list.

```
array_demo.forEach((item, index) => {
  array_demo.push({type: 'demo'});
  console.warn(index);
});
```

Comment: Do it on another array instead of doing it in place

Answer (score 1):

You could count the occurence and insert if found the right number of apperance and add a new object into the array.

For counting and keeping the logic, this appoach uses an object with the wanted types as keys and all other values, like `size` and `type` for inserting.

> ```
> {
>     all: {
>         count: 0,
>         size: 5,
>         type: 'toys'
>     },
>     fruit: {
>         count: 0,
>         size: 2,
>         type: 'clothes'
>     }
> }
> ```

```js
var array = [{ type: 'all' }, { type: 'all' }, { type: 'all' }, { type: 'fruit'}, { type: 'all' }, { type: 'all' }, { type: 'fruit' }, { type: 'all' }, { type: 'all' }, { type: 'fruit' }, { type: 'fruit' }],
    types = { all: { count: 0, size: 5, type: 'toys' }, fruit: { count: 0, size: 2, type: 'clothes' } },
    type,
    i = 0;

while (i < array.length) {
    type = types[array[i].type];
    if (type && ++type.count === type.size) {
        array.splice(++i, 0, { type: type.type });
        type.count = 0;
    }               
    ++i;
}

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the data, and use 2 outer counters (`fruit`, and `all`) to count the number of occurrences of each one. For each object that has one of the types, increment the counter, and check if it's the 2nd fruit / 5th all. If it matches the criteria return a new array with the original and the added object. Afterwards flatten all sub arrays by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Note: The solution uses [@NinaScholz types object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48420511/5157454) to make it more generic.

```js
const data = [{"type":"all"},{"type":"all"},{"type":"all"},{"type":"fruit"},{"type":"all"},{"type":"all"},{"type":"fruit"},{"type":"all"},{"type":"all"},{"type":"fruit"},{"type":"fruit"}];

const types = {
    all: { count: 0, size: 5, type: 'toys' },
    fruit: { count: 0, size: 2, type: 'clothes' }
};

const result = [].concat(...data.map((o) => {
  const to = types[o.type];

  return !to || ++to.count % to.size ? o : [o, { type: to.type }];
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of reduce and keep a count of all and fruits

```js
const array_demo = [
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit'},
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'fruit' }
]

let all = 0;
let fruit = 0;
const newArray = array_demo.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  if(item.type === 'all') {
     if(all === 4) {
       acc.push(item);
       acc.push({type: 'toys'})
       all = 0;
       return acc;
     } else {
       all++;
     }
  }else if(item.type === 'fruit') {
    if(fruit === 1) {
       acc.push(item);
       acc.push({type: 'clothes'})
       fruit = 0;
       return acc;
     } else {
       fruit++;
     }
    
  }
  acc.push(item);
  return acc;
  
}, []);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and traditional approach:

```js
let init = [
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit'},
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'fruit' }
]

let last = [];
let allCounter = 0;
let fruitCounter = 0;

for (let type of init) {
 last.push(type);

 if (type.type == 'all' ) {
  allCounter++;
  if (allCounter == 5) {
   last.push({type:'toys'})
   allCounter = 0;
  }
 } else if (type.type == 'fruit') {
  fruitCounter++;
  if (fruitCounter == 2) {
   last.push({type: 'clothes'})
   fruitCounter = 0;
  }
 }
}

console.warn(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, same result

```
function insertion(my_array){
    var i=0,
        j=0,
        n=my_array.length,
        k=0;
    while(k<n){
        if(my_array[k].type=='all'){
            i++;console.log(i);
        }else if(my_array[k].type=='fruit'){
            j++;console.log(j);
        }
        if(i==5){
            k++;
            my_array.splice(k,0,{ type: 'toys' });
            i = 0;
            n++;
        }else if(j==2){
            k++;
            my_array.splice(k,0,{ type: 'clothes' });
            j = 0;
            n++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return my_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = 
[
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit'},
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'all' },
 { type: 'fruit' },
 { type: 'fruit' }
];

var result = [];
var allCounter = 0;
var fruitCounter = 0;
data.forEach(function(item,index){
  result.push(item);
  if(item.type == "all"){
    allCounter++;
  }
  if(item.type == "fruit"){
    fruitCounter++;
  }
  if(allCounter == 5){
    result.push({"type":"toys"});
    allCounter = 0;
  }
  if(fruitCounter == 2){
    result.push({"type":"clothes"})
    fruitCounter = 0;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar need solved with:

```js
const concatAt = (array, predicate, value) => array.reduce(
    (c, n, idx) => {
        const at = typeof predicate === 'function' ? predicate(idx, n, array) : predicate === idx
        const newValue = typeof value === 'function' ? value(n, idx, array) : value
        return at ? [...c, n, newValue] : [...c, n]
    } , [])
const idOddIndex = n => n % 2
const isNth = nth => n => n % nth === nth - 1
const increment = n => n + 1

console.log(concatAt([0, 1, 3, 4, 6], idOddIndex, increment)) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
concatAt([0, 1, 3, 4, 6], isNth(3), increment) // [0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6]
```

I hope it will help someone.